# Simple executable file in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I created file `jupyter.sh` and placed it on my Desktop. Here is what inside the file:

```
#!/bin/bash
jupyter notebook
```

I also executed command `chmod +x jupyter.sh`

Now when I double click on the file, gedit opens it, while I would like it to be executed.

Any thoughts?

Comment: more suited for https://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the correct settings in Nautilus 
(File → Preferences )

[image: nautilus]

Comment: @Ixer Thank you, I my case it was under Edit -> Preferences